# SQL Injection Problem

Tags: sql-injection

I was practising on OWASP Mutillidae, and I met a problem. There's a task that examines our knowledge of UNION query.

The vulnerable query is:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='
```

The **accounts** table has 5 columns, and we want to obtain **schema_name** from **information_schema.schemata**

So I write [John' UNION ...] in the username box and the query should become to this:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username='John' UNION SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,schema_name,NULL FROM information_schema.schemata
```

But it will return **Syntax error** or **the number of columns is wrong**.

How should I write the malicious string to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: You select 5 columns in your `union` but `accounts` contain either more or less columns. First you'll have to figure out how many columns the `accounts` table contains. Either by starting with one `NULL` and adding until you have a result, or look at the result of the request. I would expect it to contain the result where you can infer the amount of columns.